Story about a pig(?) going to the jungle and needing to defeat a clan of tigers
I have a recollection of this story from my childhood (we're talking 30-35 odd years ago here). I'm fairly sure the main character was a pig (or some other similar harmless farmyard animal). He becomes lost, (possibly running away from home), and ends up in a jungle, where the other animals are living in fear of a clan of tigers. I think the tigers were based in an ancient temple of some kind.
The pig eventually gets the animals to band together to drive the tigers away, or possibly get them to live in harmony together, I don't really remember many of the details.
This was a kids book, so relatively innocent; and possibly not very long - not a single sitting reading, but certainly not a long novel.
I have a vague recollection that the cover of the book was predominantly white, and also seem to remember it being smaller than a normal book?
Sorry for the extreme vagueness, but I must have been no more than 5-6 at the time I read it! It's quite possible I'm mixing up parts of several different books I read/had read to me at the time.
